# XFCE on Arch - move windows using Winkey+Arrow like in Windows

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, window-manager

I want to be able to stick a window to the left or right using Winkey+l/r arrows, minimize it with Winey+down, and maximize it with Winkey+up . How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Settings panel, then to the Window Manager, Keyboard Tab. In here you can assign Win+Arrows to Tile window to the right, Tile window to the left, and also to Maximize and Minimize window.

Comment: Thank you !! How can I open and close applications from plank using winkey 1-9 ?

Comment: I've never used plank. But from a few google queries a deduce that plank does not support that. You might wanna give a go to a different dock app.

Comment: You can use Hide window for Minimize, since there is no Minimize window option. It has the same functionality.